# Adding an image via pure JS

Tags: javascript

I am new in JS,please help me.I have 4 images with the same class name and a hidden div which is displayed when one of 4 images is clicked. How i can add to my div the image which one is clicked? I do not want to  write a function for every image.Is it possible with my code?

```
 <a href="#"><img onClick="show()"class="img" src="css/images1/img1.png"></a>
 <a href="#"><img onClick="show()"class="img" src="css/images1/img2.png"></a>
 <a href="#"><img onClick="show()"class="img" src="css/images1/img3.png"></a>
 <a href="#"><img onClick="show()"class="img" src="css/images1/img4.png"></a>
<div class="gallery"></div>
<script>
    function show(){
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
        x.style.display="block";    
        x.innerHTML='<img src=css/images1/img1.jpg>';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the "src" of the element that was clicked:

```
function show(src){
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
    x.style.display="block"; 
    x.innerHTML = '<img src="' + src + '">';
}
```

Then for your html `<img/>` tags pass in their src to `show`:

```
<a href="#"><img onClick="show(this.src)"class="img" src="css/images1/img1.png"></a>
```

**Edit:** if you must select "gallery" by className, use `getElementsByClassName` as you originally had.

Comment: OP changed the HTML. At least part of the answer is invalid.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. I made changes per OP's desire to select elements by class name :)